# Galera cluster maria DB

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

What will be the best practice to deploy Gallera cluster having two physical servers (Server A and Server B).

first Option

1. Galera Arbitrator (Where it should be configured in A or B or in any
   other system)
2. Can i have like one DB node 1 in server A and the other two DB nodes 2,3 in Server B.

Will the cluster works if the server B goes down with both node 2,3 unavailable.

Comment: You are better off with this question at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is to have *three* different locations for 3 physical servers.  (One could be garbd.)

If you put two nodes (regular and/or garbd) in the same *physical* location, you are vulnerable to earthquake, hurricane, flood, etc.